# What is the meaning of "incandescent"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> But this time the machine has made the opposite mistake, detecting a
> virus that is not there in routine swabs taken from people who have
> come in with other problems – an overdose, a heart attack, a urine
> infection – and this doesn’t sound like such a bad thing on the
> surface; perhaps it’ll be nice to be able to say, ‘You know, we
> thought you had the virus, but you don’t.’ [...] I am outraged that
> this error has happened. On top of all the other vile facets of this
> dismal pandemic – its effects on young and old, its disgusting,
> disproportionate grip on those who are already disadvantaged – this
> feels like a twist too far. I am **incandescent**.

I don't think the bolded incandescent is saying the author is literally glowing white. But then what does it mean?

Comment: Shorthand for _incandescent with rage_ (3rd definition [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incandescent)

Comment: What's the source on this, out of curiosity? Google searching with the text of the quote only turns up this question.

Comment: Source: [The Book About Getting Older](https://books.google.it/books?id=0LHSDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT224&lpg=PT224&dq=%22routine+swabs+taken+from+people%22&source=bl&ots=TDLTjmK7F4&sig=ACfU3U3kIKqfLQ2A26orQxyEPAW4Aq46ig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuzdOjoanyAhUMCewKHUXNALUQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22routine%20swabs%20taken%20from%20people%22&f=false) by Lucy Pollock

Comment: "I am incandescent" means "I am *extremely* angry."  The idea is that you are so angry you feel like you're burning inside.  The Anger character from the movie [Inside Out](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/) offers a good visualization of the concept - he glows a bit and flames shoot out of his head when he's angry.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To say something is incandescent is to say it is heated to the degree that it emits light. For example, incandescent light bulbs are the ones with a filament that becomes super-heated when electricity flows through it.

"Heated" can mean literally hot or angry. So, incandescent is metaphorically saying the person is super-heated to an extreme degree.

Comment: So, is a red-hot iron incandescent?

Comment: @OmarL Absolutely, yes.

Comment: @OmarL by definition, anything that is **red**-hot is incandescent.

Comment: @OmarL Another common example of incandescence (in the scientific sense) is the sun, which is incandescent gas.

Comment: What about a flame, which vary in color and are sometimes blue or white? Or, an LED or something like that, which may practically any color?

Comment: @OmarL that's getting towards physics rather than language, but flames are incandescent as the light is due to heat by 'black body radiation', but LEDs are not because they generate light via a different quantum mechanical mechanism, the 'photoelectric effect', where the electrons are 'excited' by electricity not heat. Back to language, 'incandescent' and 'candle' both come from the Latin word 'candere' and candles are incandescent.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Well, thanks for the earworm!

Answer (score 6):

The particular usage in the quote provided by the OP would seem to be a contraction of "incandescent with rage". The whole of the quote describes the things the writer is angry about, so the possible alternative meanings of bright or impressive are clearly not relevant.

This usage of incandescent is so common that it is specifically listed in the [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incandescent) definition of the word.

> 3. ADJECTIVE
>    If you say that someone is incandescent with rage, you mean that they are extremely angry.
>
> [literary]
> It makes me incandescent with fury. [+ with]
> Synonyms: furious, angry, mad [informal], raging   More Synonyms of incandescent

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence

> Incandescence is the emission of electromagnetic radiation (including visible light) from a hot body as a result of its high temperature.[1] The term derives from the Latin verb incandescere, to glow white.[2] A common use of incandescence is the incandescent light bulb, now being phased out.

Extreme anger causes the face to flush red, *as if it were glowing red hot*.

Comment: Re "Extreme anger causes the face to flush red..." not always, and that's not even considering those whose natural melanin levels make it difficult or impossible to tell.

Comment: @jamesqf the metaphor was invented by people with low natural melanin levels.

Answer (score 1):

It's written in a slightly confusing way. English-speakers use brightness are a metaphor for attractiveness or compentency. A good worker is a shining star, or is dazzling you with her abilities, or she's on fire (doing her job quickly and perfectly), or she's incandescent. By itself "I am incandescent" means "I am doing an amazingly good job". We commonly use the word incandescent in that way, to mean "very, very impressive".

But English speakers also like to use fire and heat metaphors for anger: a white-hot rage, burning with jealousy, a smoldering hatred, a fiery rage. But you have to say "rage" or "jealousy" for that to work -- we might equally well say a white-hot, fiery ... passionate *love*.

The person writing that sample probably assumed you could tell they were angry and decided to shorten "incandescent fury" (or something like that) to just incandescent. But it's confusing. I had to read it a few times. At first I assumed they meant that despite all of the problems, or maybe because of them, they were doing their job much better than normal.

Comment: Personally I would say "It's an incoherent rant", not "It's written in a slightly confusing way". It is completely unclear *what* the writer is throwing a tantrum about, IMO.

Comment: I'm glad somebody got that there is more to *incandescent* than rage. It can be a metaphor for excitement or excellence, as well. However, the quoted piece is certainly about rage and anger. We are clued in by *"I am outraged"*.

Comment: @alephzero It looks like a blog post from a nurse, complaining about false-positive COVID tests on non-COVID patients being the last straw. As just unediting  writing from a regular person, not claiming to be a writer, I don't want to be too harsh.

Comment: @MarkGB Hmmm...my point is that "incandescence" is 100% excitement or excellence, *unless* something else is specified. I guess I need to emphasize that more.

Comment: If you wanted to edit for better emphasis, I would suggest you can do that by changing one word: instead of ***"passionate"*** love, use ***"incandescent"*** love.